# "$1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$" implies an eigenvalue of $A$ is a root of unity?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a square matrix. If $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$, then is it true that there is an eigenvalue of $A$ which is a root of unity?

Comment: Hint: What is the contrapositive statement?

Comment: It depends if $A$ is real or complex (actually it depends on considering only real eigenvalues or complex ones)

Comment: @YannHamdaoui $A$ is a real matrix but eigenvalues can be complex

Comment: @Kira then you can trigonalize $A$ in $\mathbb{C}$, with eigenvalues on the diagonal. Now what is $A^n$ in this basis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k$. That [implise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Further_properties), that $A^n$ has the eigenvalues $\lambda_1^n, \dots, \lambda_k^n$.

If some of $\lambda_i^n =1$, that implies $\lambda_i$ is [the $n$-th root of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#General_definition).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is true. To see it you should only consider eigenvalues in a Jordan form of $A$.

In two other answers authors do not proof that each eigenvalue of $A^n$ is a n-degree of an eigenvalue of $A$. But you can see it consider matrix $A$ in a Jordan form and take its n-th degree and for this triangle matrix calculate characteristic polynomial which contains all information about eigenvalues repetition factors.

Answer (score 2):

We prove easily that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $P(\lambda$) is an eigenvalue of $P(A)$ where $P$ is a polynomial.

Now take  $P(x)=x^n$ and by the hypothesis we have for some $\lambda$, $\lambda^n=1$. Conclude.